# React-Native HTTP response with content-type image and empty body

Tags: react-native

I am trying to obtain the image blobs to encode them in base 64 so I can later pass them to an Image component. This way I would reduce the time of rendering a new image by avoiding the time it takes to request it.

I have tried using both `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` in the following way:

```
fetch('http://thinktheology.co.uk/images/uploads/2598-75772.jpg')
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

They both have the following response:

[image: Response]

`_bodyInit` and `_bodyText` are both empty strings. I have also tried requesting an HTML document, it worked fine.

**Update: As of March 2nd, obtaining this type of response is not yet implemented in React Native, this is why I receive an empty body.**

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in an app I am currently working on. I wanted to download and cache the image so it would could be rendered quickly when it was to be viewed. I didn't use fetch though, I used [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs). The download file function made it quite easy.

Comment: Hey - thanks. Before giving it a try, how will this be bundled when I build my app for the App Store? Is it a non-issue? I haven't uploaded a RN app to the store yet so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @FaureHu I haven't submitted an app to the app store yet but I can't imagine this would cause an issue. It is just a way to use the native way to cache data in javascript. You will have to clean up this data at some point, depending on how you want to do it. But as a reference, I looked at snapchat and they cache a lot of images/video from their discover section, not sure when they decide to actually delete it though.

Comment: I was in doubt because it asked me to configure a bunch of stuff on Xcode, but I guess that stays within the `.xproj` files. I have tried react-native-fs and it works, thanks!